# how to use swagger with http and https (drf)

Tags: http, django-rest-framework, https, swagger, schema

How do I do django rest framework plus swagger so that in 'schemes' it comes out to make both http and https queries?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyiHo.png)

try to add some settings in 'SWAGGER_SETTINGS' but it doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyCXL.png)